# matlab fill array with vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

I wish to populate an nxn matrix with vectors. I have the following:

```
[x y] = meshgrid(a);
for i:size(a,1)
    for j:size(a,2)
        b = [x(i,j),y(i,j) 0];
    end
end
```

I think may be being a bit naive here as I am expecting a range of different numbers within the vector elements of b. Instead I am getting the elements of b are all equal. also

```
size(b) = 1 3
size(b(1,1)) = 1 1
```

I am expecting size(b(1,1)) = 1 3 as each element in b should be a vector of length 3. can someone tell me where I have gone wrong? Thanks very much.

Comment: `b{i,j} = [x(i,j),y(i,j) 0];` ?

Comment: hi Junuxx - when I try this I get ??? Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the value of `b` in the loop.
Try:

```
[x y] = meshgrid(a);
b = zeros( size(a,1) size(a,2) 3);
for i:size(a,1)
    for j:size(a,2)
        b(i,j,:) = [x(i,j),y(i,j) 0];
    end
end
```

Comment: hi Andrey, when I try that I get: ???Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts....

Comment: @brucezepplin, what is `a` in your code? Also see my revised code

Comment: Hi Andrey - a is simply an image I am reading in: a = imread('circle.png') and then a = a(:,:,1);

Comment: regarding the output of your updated code, I get size(b) = [70 70 3]. I am expecting size(b(1,1)) = [1  3] however I am getting [1 1]. Each element in b should be a vector of size 3, however I am not getting this.

Comment: @brucezepplin, in that case you should use a cell array

Comment: hi Andrey, I have used a cell array and that's worked fine. thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways how you could fill an n-by-n array `b` with vectors:

(1) You can create a n-by-n-by-3 array, so that `squeeze(b(i,j,:))` returns the vector `i,j` as a 3-by-1 array:

```
a=1:3,
[x y] = meshgrid(a);
b = cat(3,x,y,zeros(size(x));
```

(2) You can create an n-by-n cell array so that `b{i,j}` returns the vector `i,j`

```
a=1:3,
[x y] = meshgrid(a);
b = arrayfun(@(x,y)[x,y],x,y,'uni',false);
```